# Overlay 2 rasters using {rayshader} using add_overlay. Wrong dimensions after resampling

Tags: raster, r

I have two raster objects `elev` and `image`, which have different resolution but same extent. `elev` contains elevation data, and `image` is an rgb raster. What I would like to do, is to plot the elevation map in 3d and add the layer from the image on top.

```
library(raster)
elev <- raster("swissALTI3D2019-3.tif")
image = brick("TK100_Dufour-5.tif")
res(image)
#[1] 4.998897 4.997546
res(elev)
#[1] 0.5 0.5
extent(image) == extent(elev)
#[1] TRUE
```

In order to make sure the two raster have the same resolution, I use `resample()` function, and create the `elev_res` object

```
elev_res <- resample(elev, image, method="bilinear")
res(elev_res) == res(image)
#[1] TRUE
```

In order to plot them on ray shader, I am then transform them to a matrix.

```
elev_res_mat = raster_to_matrix(elev_res)
image_mat <- raster_to_matrix(image)
```

But when I run the following code, I get the following error `Error in *tmp*[, , 4] : incorrect number of dimensions`

```
elev_res_mat %>%
  sphere_shade(texture = "imhof1") %>%
  add_overlay(image_mat, alphalayer = 0.5) %>%
  plot_map()
```

Comment: you do `elev_res <- resample(elev, x, method="bilinear")`, but there is no `x` (should that be `image`. Otherwise, can you make a minimal, self-contained reproducible example?(create similar data with code, so that we can run it?). You added a lot of stuff about the resampling, but how is that relevant? Also, you say that "image is a rgb raster". Do you mean it has three layers (r, g, b)? As you are using `raster` rather than `brick` you are only reading one layer.

Comment: Hi, yes I will try to make a reprex for the two rasters, but need to figure out how. 
I have changed the code to `brick()` indeed, and change the `x` to `image`.
The idea is that I use `resample()` to match the resolution of the higher resolution raster to the lower resolution one.